# Frontend search does not work when Sphinx Search for Magento is re-indexing

Tags: catalogsearch, search, indexing, advanced-search

Frontend search does not work when Sphinx Search for Magento is re-indexing. It is set to re-index whenever the catalogsearch_fulltext indexing is done for Magento.

Whenever I run **php indexer.php --reindex catalogsearch_fulltext**, searches on the frontend will timeout due to a lack of server response.

Answer (score 3):

Please familiarize yourself with the [Sphinx indexer reference](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/archives/1.10/ref-indexer.html) and use the `--rotate` argument or the [`seamless_rotate`](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/archives/1.10/conf-seamless-rotate.html) configuration option.

Comment: Magento does the indexing and updates the Sphinx table and reindexes Sphinx automatically. I have already tried running the indexer via bash with the --rotate argument, however it did not add in any new entries from Magento.

Comment: @BigJoe what Magento version are you running? A patch was just released that “resolves search query failures that occur when reindexing is in process.” The patch is for EE 1.12.x, EE 1.13.x, and EE 1.14.x.

Comment: We're running CE 1.8.1